# tar a directory without directories inside

Tags: tar

I am trying to create a compressed file of sublime text snippets.  The snippets I want to include are in the subdirectory snippets of my current directory

All around the web, as far as I can see I should do

`tar czf snippets.tar.gz -C snippets .`

However, if I do that I get an archive, which looking at it from GNOME Nautilus, shows an archive with a directory named `.` in it and the files within that directory.

I also tried (and `-C snippets/`)

`tar czf snippets.tar.gz -C snippets *`

but then I get the following error

`tar: snippets: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: snippets.tar.gz: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: supporting: Cannot stat: No such file or directory
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors`

but the directory is definitely there and there doesn't seem anything wrong with its permissions

`drwxr-xr-x  2 alan alan 12288 Aug 25 11:15 snippets
-rw-r--r--  1 alan alan    45 Aug 25 11:26 snippets.tar.gz
drwxr-xr-x 13 alan alan  4096 Aug 25 09:59 supporting`

I'm running debian testing, so I guess there is a possibility that tar is broken at the moment, but I rather doubt it, given the system is so dependant on it.  So what am I doing wrong>

Comment: `./` always represents the current directory, it's totally normal. Is this your first meeting with *nix? :->

Comment: I have been using *nix for 20 years, but its not correct to have ./ inside the archive I am sure.  I've just been able to create an archive how I want it using gnome's file-roller - which is OK for a quick manual update - but I wanted to automate the process via a git-hook and that needs a command line approach.

Comment: Then fill a bugreport for GNOME Nautilus to hide the ./ directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use -C switch when creating tar files. 
Try it like this:

```
tar -czf snippets.tar.gz snippets/*
```

Or something like:

```
cd snippets;tar -czf ../snippets.tar.gz *;cd ..
```